# Get meeting request message after send/update via EWS

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices

We have a need to store a record of all correspondences sent. So far, no problem for emails. But for calendar invites, etc. not so much.

When I call GetItem, it returns me the expected Meeting (IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request) object, and the MimeContent value for it is a calendar file. Again, expected.

I've long used the OWA trick to get .eml files out (drag email into a new message, download) and doing the same with a meeting produces an .eml file of the meeting invitation (with Message-ID) with the invite as an attachment. **This is the file I want**, except via EWS.

OWA performs a REST API call to an operation called 'CreateAttachmentFromLocalFile' which appears to say 'put item (Item ID) as an attachment to this draft'. This is as close as I've gotten to a solution, which appears that I need to create a dummy draft just to attach this file to, then download the result attachment-as-EML.

Please tell me there's better way. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not sure I understand - if you already get MIME content from MimeContent returned by GetItem, do you need the data in some other format?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - I need the invitation email/message (an .eml file). The MimeContent for a Meeting Request is an .ics file.

Comment: You can create an EML file explicitly in your code: add `Subject`, `Content-Type` (text/calendar) etc headers plus the ICS part you get from EWS.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I'm specifically needing the message as it is from Exchange with the headers intact, including the Message ID. Reconstituting an .eml file even if I got all the details is just reinventing the wheel and prone to bugs.

Comment: Is there a particular header that you think you might miss? Exchange does not do anything that you can't do on your own.

Comment: Building the eml in code is the last resort for reasons I won't go into. I want a verbatim, from-the-source, representation of the email. OWA calls APIs to generate EML already, so there must be a way from EWS

Comment: If you want *all* properties (especially the MAPI props used by Outlook), MIME is not the best format.

Comment: I'm just looking for the same output as OWA provides (an EML file). Docs here suggest that it should be returned (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/mimecontent - 'Parent elements') but it's not